# Node.js with SQL: ERR_EMPTY_QUERY

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to create a service with `MySQL` as database. I have my query stored in the database and am calling it in the `node.js` service. It is a two step process as the first query will give the query to be the run as the result to next connection. However my first part is working fine but when the connection moves to second part it gives `ERR_EMPTY_QUERY`.

**Here is my code.** The error is at the second part `connection.query(dbresult, function (err, done))`.

```
 var async = require('async');

 module.exports.getChart = function (chartcode,filter,callback){


   var fuelweekquery= "SELECT * FROM t_chart_val where CHART_CODE=?"
    if (null == filter || "week"==(filter)){
        result= fuelweekquery;


    }

    async.parallel([
    function (callback) {
        //if(null==filter || "day"==(filter))
        pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {

            connection.query(result,[chartcode], function (err, done) {
                if (err) {
                    connection.release();
                }
                for (var i in done) {

                    dbresult = done[i].CHART_ATTR_VAL;
                }
                    callback(err,  done);

                    }   
                );


        });
    },
    function (callback) {
        //if(null==filter || "day"==(filter))
        pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
          connection.query(dbresult, function (err, done) {
                if (err) {
                    connection.release();
                }
                //connection.release();
                console.log(done);
                callback(err, done);

                }   
            );

        });
    },


], function (err, results) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    //console.log('queries finished', results);
    callback(null, results);
});

}
```

Comment: I don't see any promises - or anything to ensure one operation completes before the next one starts.

Comment: the previous operation completes as i saw while debugging. The problem is when it reaches the next part. I  recon the dbresult value is not carrying onto the next connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to caolan async documentation ([Source](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel)),

> Run the tasks collection of functions in parallel, without waiting until the previous function has completed. If any of the functions pass an error to its callback, the main callback is immediately called with the value of the error. Once the tasks have completed, the results are passed to the final callback as an array.

Therefore it does not wait for the first in the array to complete before executing the second, for this I would recommend you use **async waterfall**

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        //Your DB operation
        callback(null, dbresult );
    },
    function(dbresult, callback) {
        // use dbresult for your second operation
        callback(null, 'done');
    }
], function (err, result) {
    // result now equals 'done'
});
```